# How to check Oracle directory I created is valid?

Tags: oracle11g

As I read in oracle documentation oracle does not check the directory I have created is valid or not. Is there anyway to check if the directory is valid? I'm getting weird error in exporting database and I suspected to the directory!

Comment: You could write a small test function to call UTL_FILE to try to create a file in the directory, and see if it is successful.  Show us the errors.